# How to move apps on SD-card to bigger SD-card without PC

Tags: samsung, external-sd, tablet, app2sd

I need simple steps to switch full `sd card` that have some apps on that sd card larger memory I need to switch from full`sd card` to my new 128GB `sd card` but i have no computer at all, no laptop as well.

I only have 1 tablet Samsung Galaxy Tablet model SM-T580??!! Can I just uninstall those apps before switch and insert new 128Gb `sd card`, but what happens to all my downloaded music, podcasts, etc. If I switch cards can I still listen to them if I was to later insert into another media player?

I'm beyond a newbie to using any computer (only have SM-T580 Tablet) If I uninstall my apps would I lose all my saved music& podcasts (there's a lot).

I need to know exactly step by step info & exactly what to be aware of I'm so new to my device, new to files and even how to identify them system/mine.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do it:

For simplicity I prefer to split into categories:

- Backup of files (music, documents, videos, any other media files and miscellaneous files)
- Backup of installed applications
- Other (e.g SMS/MMS attachments etc)

**Method to back up Categoty 1 Data**

Prerequisites:

- Unlimited/suitable data plan
- Must have signed to a cloud storage (or have one Google drive will do just fine)

You can easily upload the data to google drive or other similar cloud solutions.
To retrieve it you need to redownload it again.

**Method to back up Category 2 data**

To preserve the intergrity of all your apps (with thier data), you need additional app, capable of doing this. (Install in internal memory).

A good example is [Helium - App Sync and Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup&hl=en) (doesnt require  root). Other similar app is [Utimate backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.app.managerfree&hl=en), alternatively browse around playstore to pick one there.

It allows you to choose the apps you want to backup. Again if there is no enough space on internal memory use the cloud solution e.g dropbox or similar.

[image: Helium]

**Method to back up category 3 data**

This requires much less space than the 2 above. You can just back up in internal memory as well.

**Retreiving data after installing new sd card**

- All the data that have been backup up can then be downloaded again, using the cloud solution previously used and from internal memory.

Comment: Well I am a root user so I use the app manager in (ROM toolbox) similar to Ultimate backup mentioned above, however I am not sure if it works on on non rooted phones so I just gave non root options, all these apps don't need a PC to perfom bckups so I thought to include them. And they allow backing up of applications ( with thier app data) so the apps are kept intact, just as they were in old sd card